# (Laravel) How to implement sass and tailwindcss in webpack.mix.js

Tags: css, laravel, sass

Problem is that I can only use the code A or code B in the webpack.mix.js file without any error.
I use jetstream which uses tailwindcss in my dashboard view and I use sass in another view. When I only use code B, the dashboard can't compile obviously the style.

So how can I use both (tailwindcss, postCss and sass) without any error?

Code A:

```
  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
     require('postcss-import'),
     require('tailwindcss'),
 ])
 .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

Code B:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just appending them?

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css/sass.css')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css/postCss.css', [
       require('postcss-import'),
       require('tailwindcss'),
   ])
   .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

You'll need to include both `public/css/sass.css` and `public/css/postCss.css` with this solution.

Comment: Sass is compiled correctly with your solution, now I've got an error after running npm dev. There is sth. wrong with the .webpackConfig

Answer (score 0):

First, please confirm you installed the following packages in `package.json`.

if not, please install with `npm`

```
resolve-url-loader
sass
sass-loader
tailwindcss
```

> If you added the `sass` code in `webpack.mix.js`, Laravel recommends installing the packages related to `sass` when you run `npm run dev` and will install automatically.
> But it will work when you run the command `npm run dev` again.

Then, the following `webpack.mix.js` works for me to work with `sass` and `tailwindcss`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/home.scss', 'public/css/home')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```